# How to remove elements based on id

Tags: jointjs

I want to remove elements based on ID with double click

Tried this but it is not working:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick', function (cellView,cell)
                {
                    selectedId = cellView.model.id;
                    selected = cellView.model;
                    $.each(cellsAdded, function(index, value)
                    {
                        if(selectedId !== cellsAdded[index])
                        {
                            selected.remove();
                        }
                    });
                });
```

These are the cells in the graph:

```
var cellsAdded = graph.addCells([sidebar, rect, circle1, circle2, circle3, rectGroup0, diamond]);
```

All of the above cells have ids and I dont want to remove them, I only want to remove other elements which are not part of the above

Comment: Could you post some more information on what `paper` and `cell` are? Also, are you receiving any error messages? Thanks.

Comment: Updated the question. I am not getting any errors